# Calculate, if it exists, $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

Let $f(x) =  \dfrac{sin(x^3)+1}{\int_{-1}^{x} sin(t^3) dt +x +4} $

Calculate, if it exists, $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx$

Comment: Do you know a trick for integrating $g'/g$ ?

Comment: @Matthew Towers
 Sure, ln |g| + c

Comment: Well, does it help? Especially when you remember that the integral of an odd function over an interval of the form [-a, a] is zero.

Comment: I think I did, in the end that gave me ln (5/3). Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds right to me. Maybe write it up as an answer?